# What's the path in jblough / Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library?

Tags: android, pdf

Looking at the following website:
https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library

He's listed the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourPdfViewerActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, "PATH TO PDF GOES HERE");
startActivity(intent);
```

What will that path be and where I be placing this PDF file?

I have placed a test PDF file in assests folder, res/raw. Pushed a file from the ddms in data/data/project, and in libs folder as well. I tried the following but I am still getting file not found:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "test.pdf";
String path = "android.resource://com.example.test3/raw/test.pdf";
String path = "file:///android_assets/test.pdf";
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/test.pdf";
```

Comment: Sheesh then how about a solution if you think it is so OBVIOUS?

Comment: Added what I have tried so far.

Comment: second one but you forgot `/` befor `test.pdf`, i think ... if you wana take if from assets you have to copy it first on storage then provide path to copy

Comment: Is there no more direct approach? Because eventually the file will come from web service.

Comment: `final File cacheDir = context.getDir("cache", 0);if(!cacheDir.exists()) cacheDir.mkdirs();final File fileContent = new File(cacheDir, "some_name.pdf"); psedo_method_DownloadFile(url_from, fileContent_as_File_to); final String path = fileContent.getPath();`

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Ran it first time, it created that folder, then I placed the file in that folder and ran it again and it was able to find the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final File cacheDir = context.getDir("cache", 0);
if(!cacheDir.exists()) cacheDir.mkdirs();
final File fileContent = new File(cacheDir, "test1.pdf");
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/test1.pdf";
path = fileContent.getPath();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, path);
startActivity(intent);
```

Ran it first time, it created that folder, then I placed the file in that folder and ran it again and it was able to find the file. Placed the file from the ddms. Answered by Selvin.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest, which worked for me:

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() 
            + File.separator + "pdfName.pdf");

String path = f.getPath();

Intent intent = new Intent(this, BulaActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, path);
startActivity(intent);
```