# creating folder in android emulator

Tags: android

I am developing an android application. I need to create a folder in the internal memory, but when I try to create the folder I get the error below. I am running in an emulator.

```
 mkdir failed for /mnt/New Folder , read only file system
```

I have tried many paths, but still the error persists. The only folder that I am able to create is called "cache", but I cannot browse it by my file chooser activity.
Any idea where is the suitable place to create folders without any permissions?

Comment: Have you read: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal ?

Comment: You can only create a folder on a filesystem or parent folder where you have write permission.  You need to look at the external storage API, or if you prefer (but with more limitations, particularly on accessing the data from a connected PC), the internal storage one.

Comment: Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/19818901/1275777?

Comment: What do you mean by?
"but I cannot browse it by my file chooser activity"

Comment: @NomanArain inside my application i'm using an activity that allows the user to select a file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by this from a Context object (like Activity).

```
File files_folder = getFilesDir(); 
File files_child = new File(files_folder, "files_child"); 
files_child.mkdirs(); 
File created_folder = getDir("custom", MODE_PRIVATE); 
File f1_child = new File(created_folder, "custom_child"); 
f1_child.mkdirs();
```

The function

```
getFilesDir()
```

will get the folder data/data/yourpackagename/files in internal memory. And the function

```
getDir("custom", MODE_PRIVATE)
```

will create a folder name app_custom in your app internal folder.

Answered by Minhtdh

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you call internal memory is atualy the external memory (which can be open by

file chooser activity, the real internal memory only can be open if you have rooted)

If that true, you should chek those belows:
- first, you will need the write storeage permission in Manisfest

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`
- then you should use `

> String path =
>   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
>   "/yourfoldername"

` 
than

> mnt/yourfoldername

- at last you should use `mkdirs` to create folder than `mkdir`

Comment: i have no problem in accessing the external storage (SD card) , but it is essential to my application to make a folder on the internal memory (Phone memory)... is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: You can achieve it by this from a Context object (like Activity)
`File files_folder = getFilesDir();
        File files_child = new File(files_folder, "files_child");
        files_child.mkdirs();
        
  File created_folder = getDir("custom", MODE_PRIVATE);
  File f1_child = new File(created_folder, "custom_child");
  f1_child.mkdirs();`
function `getFilesDir()` will get the folder data/data/yourpackagename/files in internal memory
function `getDir("custom", MODE_PRIVATE)` will create a folder name `app_custom` in your app internal folder